# Filter component visibility by running user

Tags: lightning, component, lightning-components, lightning-page

Can anyone see, why this wouldn't work?

[image: Lightning Page]

I have also tried:

- userinfo.getuserid()
- user.id
- account.OwnerId

Comment: This sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Anyways your report, or list view all you can filter via `My Accounts` filter, i.e. only records which you created will be visible to you, so what are you trying to achieve extra here.

Comment: Do you want display lightning component based on the current user?

Comment: @AnkaiahBandi yes, the component doesn't have filter by my accounts at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use The record's Owner.email as the filter field, and use $User.email as the value.